# Add New Item Link not appear in Sharepoint List

Tags: 2010, splist

Add New Item Link not appear in Sharepoint List.

I logging with admin account(having full control).

[image]

How to resolve ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check this out:

> **1.** Go to the list that is lacking the link
>
> **2.** Select the view that doesn’t have the link appearing
>
> **3.** Select Edit Page from the Site Action menu
>
> **4.** Edit the list web part properties
>
> **5.** Note the current Toolbar setting
>
> **6.** Change the Toolbar setting and click Apply. Any selection other than No Toolbar should cause the link to appear after you click Apply.
>
> **7.** Reset the Toolbar setting to that noted  in 5 and click Apply again. The link should be appearing correctly.
>
> **8.** If you need to do this for additional views on the list select the view from the Selected View pull down menu and repeat steps 5 to 7 for
>   each view.
>
> **9.** When complete click the OK button and then click the Stop Editing button in the page ribbon.

taken from:

http://kirkbarrett.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/add-new-item-link-not-appearing/

Comment: It is a bit faster to get to the right screen by using the drop down arrow on the list. My issue is with that of a Custom List. The Show Toolbar choices only show the + sign with no text like "add new item". I am assuming the text must be configured for Custom Lists, so will keep looking.

Comment: @RicahrdJenny you first need to see if there is any css applied to your page that could be effecting the visual outlook as i presume you have the add item but it only displays the plus sign? goto f12 developer tools in ie and inspect the "+" element to see if there is any custom css that is efecting it!

Answer (score 4):

1)Select Edit Page from the Site Action menu

2) Edit the list web part properties

3)settings window opens and change the Toolbar type to "Full Toolbar" which can be seen in the dropdown. 
click ok and click stop editing on the top of the page . 
you can see "add new item" link button.